# How to seperate email body from a rendered thread through IMAP?

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, mailcore2

I am fetching emails using `IMAP` but when we render a particular message body along with it fetches all replies/conversation along with it. I want to separate those messages and also want to separate a particular message body with a signature as well.

**what I received right now**

[image][image]

**What I want to achieve**

[image][image]

*HTML body for first mail i.e. receieved mail*

```
"<div style=\"padding-bottom: 20px;\"></div><div><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n<head>\n<title></title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<div dir=\"ltr\">\n<div>Hey Bhavin,<br />\n<br /></div>\nThis is LA TEST 01 to test threads for Letter<br clear=\"all\" />\n<div>\n<div><br />\n--<br />\n<div dir=\"ltr\" class=\"gmail_signature\" data-smartmail=\n\"gmail_signature\">\n<div dir=\"ltr\">\n<div>\n<div dir=\"ltr\">----------<br />\n<span style=\"font-family:georgia,serif\"><font size=\"2\">Thanks &amp;\nRegards</font><br /></span></div>\n<div>Stack<br /></div>\n<div dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"font-family:georgia,serif\"><font size=\n\"2\"><i><br /></i></font></span></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n</div>"
```

*HTML body for second mail i.e. reply*

```
"<div style=\"padding-bottom: 20px;\"></div><div><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n<head>\n<title></title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<div class=\"ydp462b3c77yahoo-style-wrap\" style=\n\"font-family: verdana, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;\">\n<div>\n<div dir=\"ltr\" data-setdir=\"false\">Hi Stack,<br />\n<br />\nThanks for the info. Let me do the test for LA TEST 01 from my side\nas well.<br /></div>\n<div><br /></div>\n<div class=\"ydp462b3c77signature\">\n<div style=\n\"font-family:verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:13px;\">\n--<br />\n<div><font size=\"2\">Thanks &amp; Regards</font></div>\n<div><b>Bhavin Bhadani</b></div>\n<div id=\"ydp267338c6yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1469425690897_2386\">\n<font size=\"2\"><i>iOS Developer&nbsp;</i></font><font face=\n\"Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif\"><br />\n</font></div>\n<div><font size=\"2\"><i><b>skype:</b>\nbhavi</i></font></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n<div><br /></div>\n<div><br /></div>\n</div>\n<div id=\"yahoo_quoted_4513314037\" class=\"yahoo_quoted\">\n<div style=\n\"font-family:\'Helvetica Neue\', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#26282a;\">\n<div>On Wednesday, 23 June, 2021, 12:09:22 pm IST, Stack Help\n&lt;stackh@gmail.com&gt; wrote:</div>\n<div><br /></div>\n<div><br /></div>\n<div>\n<div id=\"yiv6922098475\">\n<div dir=\"ltr\">\n<div>Hey Bhavin,<br />\n<br /></div>\nThis is LA TEST 01 to test threads for Letter<br clear=\"all\" />\n<div>\n<div><br />\n--<br />\n<div dir=\"ltr\" class=\"yiv6922098475gmail_signature\">\n<div dir=\"ltr\">\n<div>\n<div dir=\"ltr\">----------<br />\n<span style=\"font-family:georgia, serif;\"><font style=\n\"background-color: inherit;\" size=\"2\">Thanks &amp;\nRegards</font><br /></span></div>\n<div>Stack<br /></div>\n<div dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\n\"font-family:georgia, serif;\"><font style=\n\"background-color: inherit;\" size=\n\"2\"><i><br /></i></font></span></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n</div>"
```

I am using `MailCore 2` for iOS and `JavaMail` for Android.

Comment: This isn't an IMAP quesiton, you want to do some clever text processing on the message body after you've received it. I use jsoup for a similar pupose.

Comment: And... I don't think you're the first to ask. Look at old questions.

Comment: There is no standard for this, email clients will stitch quoted text into the reply email in literally hundreds of different ways.  Choose your most important clients (Outlook? Gmail?), find out how they do it, and munge the text/DOM as needed.  If you’re lucky, someone has done this in a library that you can leverage, but I’m not aware of any, and it’ll need to be updated everytime, for example, Outlook releases a new major version.

Comment: @Max I found out the same that there is not a single pattern for this and also tried to search out some common pattern but I am unable to find it.